# Image tag shows all columns of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Yesterday i made some experience with carrierwav, all works fine but at the image tag where normally only the image should displayed rails also shows the hole model, with `created_at` etc. Here you cann see it![image]

So now my view:

```
<% @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= treatment.category.try(:typ) %></td>
  <td><%= treatment.content %></td>
  <td><%= treatment.day %></td>
  <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">
    <%= link_to 'Löschen', [treatment.patient, treatment],
                            :confirm => 'Sind sie sicher?',
                            :method => :delete %>
    <%= treatment.paintings.each do |paint| %>                          
      <%= image_tag paint.name %>
    <% end %>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem has to be in `<%= image_tag paint.name %>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `=` from `<%= treatment.paintings.each do |paint| %>`, that is making you also print the `treatment.paintings` array.

```
    <% treatment.paintings.each do |paint| %>                          
      <%= image_tag paint.name %>
    <% end %>
```